# What does it mean "unmanaged device"?

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager, devices

My network devices seem to be "unmanaged", or perhaps "managed outside the network manager". I assume this because of syslog messages like

```
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> (eth2): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> (eth2): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> Unmanaged Device found; state CONNECTED forced. (see http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889)
```

And the link http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/191889 is a bug whose title contains "networks that are managed outside of network manager".

My `wlan2` connection logs similar messages:

```
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan2): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan2): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <info> (wlan2): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Jun 25 18:42:13 lati NetworkManager[811]: <warn> Trying to remove a non-existant call id.
```

So, where is my network managed, if not inside the network manager? Are there any consequences for this?

---

My system info:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (trusty)
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Kernel version: 3.16.0-40-generic
- Dell E7440
- Bios version: A14
- Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
- Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)

Comment: What are the contents of your /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: `auto lo` in one line, `iface lo inet loopback` in the second.

Comment: It could be that there is a line `managed=false` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. Usually that means that you have no way of controlling your network connections through the GUI.

Comment: There is indeed `managed=false` in the `[ifupdown]` section in that config file.  The rest of the lines are `plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono` and `dns=dnsmasq` in `[main]`. Any risk in making it managed? Any benefit?